# Optimizing MySQL select distinct order by limit safely

Tags: mysql, database-performance, sqlperformance

I have a problematic query that I know how to write faster, but technically the SQL is invalid and it has no guarantee of working correctly into the future.

The original, slow query looks like this:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache DISTINCT r.field_1 value
FROM table_middle m
JOIN table_right r on r.id = m.id
WHERE ((r.field_1) IS NOT NULL) 
AND (m.kind IN ('partial')) 
ORDER BY r.field_1 
LIMIT 26
```

This takes about **37 seconds**. Explain output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys         | key           | key_len | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | range  | PRIMARY,index_field_1 | index_field_1 | 9       | 1544595 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_kind    | PRIMARY       | 4       |       1 | Using where; Distinct                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The faster version looks like this; the `order by` clause is pushed down into a subquery, which is joined on and is in turn limited with distinct:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache DISTINCT value 
FROM (
  SELECT r.field_1 value
  FROM table_middle m
  JOIN table_right r ON r.id = m.id
  WHERE ((r.field_1) IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (m.kind IN ('partial')) 
  ORDER BY r.field_1 
) t
LIMIT 26
```

This takes about **2.7 seconds**. Explain output:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                  | NULL       | NULL    | 1346348 | Using temporary                                           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | m          | ref    | PRIMARY,index_kind    | index_kind | 99      | 1539558 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_field_1 | PRIMARY    | 4       |       1 | Using where                                               |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are three million rows in table_right and table_middle, and all mentioned columns are individually indexed. The query should be read as having an arbitrary `where` clause - it's dynamically generated. The query can't be rewritten in any way that prevents the where clause being easily replaced, and similarly the indexes can't be changed - MySQL doesn't support enough indexes for the number of potential filter field combinations.

Has anyone seen this problem before - specifically, select / distinct / order by / limit performing very poorly - and is there another way to write the same query with good performance that doesn't rely on unspecified implementation behaviour?

(AFAIK MariaDB, for example, ignores `order by` in a subquery because it should not logically affect the set-theoretic semantics of the query.)

#### For the more incredulous

Here's how you can create a version of database for yourself! This should output a SQL script you can run with mysql command-line client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "create database testy;"
puts "use testy;"
puts "create table table_right(id int(11) not null primary key, field_0 int(11), field_1 int(11), field_2 int(11));"
puts "create table table_middle(id int(11) not null primary key, field_0 int(11), field_1 int(11), field_2 int(11));"
puts "begin;"
3_000_000.times do |x|
  puts "insert into table_middle values (#{x},#{x*10},#{x*100},#{x*1000});"
  puts "insert into table_right values (#{x},#{x*10},#{x*100},#{x*1000});"
end
puts "commit;"
```

Indexes aren't important for reproducing the effect. The script above is untested; it's an approximation of a pry session I had when reproducing the problem manually.

Replace the `m.kind in ('partial')` with `m.field_1 > 0` or something similar that's trivially true. Observe the large difference in performance between the two different techniques, and how the sorting semantics are preserved (tested using MySQL 5.5). The unreliability of the semantics are, of course, precisely the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: But... does that second query return the correct results? I can't imagine that it does. In either MariaDB or MySQL the ORDER BY will be ignored unless there is a LIMIT supplied. Your second query only runs faster because the DB isn't having to sort millions of records.

Comment: Oh but it does, @JNevill - you should try it out (MySQL 5.5)! It doesn't take 37 seconds to sort 3 million records - that's the weird extreme inefficiency. It would be faster to create a temporary table, insert into it, and select from it, than run the first query. But I'm not eager to introduce that kind of workflow into these dynamic filtering queries.

Comment: @JNevill I added a script so you can see for yourself, should you want to.

Comment: What's the performance of `SELECT FROM table_middle m JOIN table_right r ON r.id = m.id WHERE ((r.field_1) IS NOT NULL) AND (m.kind IN ('partial')) ORDER BY r.field_1` ?

Comment: @JNevill I'm not at my work machine any more so I can't tell you directly comparable numbers, but I have a similar case here in a VM on my home machine (the one I set up using the script above). Selecting the whole multi-million table will take a while just for I/O; if I stick a `limit 10 offset 2990000` on the end then we're in the region of the second query (i.e. fast, comparitively). It's the combo of distinct + order by + limit in one query that's slow. FWIW even GNU sort can do 3 million lines in less than 4 seconds in a VM.

Comment: Hey @BarryKelly I know this post is three years old but could you find any good solution for this?

Comment: @Fabian perf is adequate (just about) with approach I described (nested order by), but longer term we're moving the DB running the arbitrary queries behind an API so we have more freedom to choose other databases, and potentially in-memory caches, to do the sort and filter. Dynamic sort and filter may be somewhat unique to our problem space though (could be approximated as "multi-million-line web spreadsheets").

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  In the absence of that, I will guess that these are missing and may be useful:

```
m:  (kind, id)
r:  (field_1, id)
```

You can turn off MariaDB's ignoring of the subquery's `ORDER BY`.

Comment: See the script I added - those create table statements are sufficient to show the issue. I'm using MySQL 5.5, not MariaDB. Indexes cannot be changed; any field may be sorted by, and any combination of fields may be filtered by. Indexes are not relied upon for these tables. Nice if they help, but they aren't expected to. There are 1000s of these tables in the app, with at most a million or two records each, and up to several 100 columns (not all indexed). I'm specifically working on optimizing the worst case; unindexed sorts and filters are acceptable, as long as they only take a second or two.

Comment: Have enough RAM to cache everything; set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of available ram.  Shrink the datatypes to minimize disk footprint.  Have lots of fast cores.  Get rid of indexes since you are optimizing for the cases where you can't use them anyway.